# ProcessEvent not called in TFS plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, tfs

Recently i have decided to create a plugin for the TFS for tracking work item changes based on ISubscriber interface.

So the workflow would be the following:
1) Work item state changes
2) Plugin catches the WorkItemChangedEvent
3) Send an email to the person specified in the Requester

As the base for my project, i used the following project from CodePlex - [The Mail Alert](https://tfsemailalert.codeplex.com/)

After i adopted it to my needs and saved compiled binaries in `%TFS-DIR%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins` the TFS restarted the tier and... that's it. On work item change the ProcessEvent method is not called, but it should be.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MailAlert
{
    public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {
        static string serverPath = "";
        static string ExternalURL = "";
        static string MailAddressFrom = "";
        static string SMTPHost = "";
        static string Password = "";
        static int Port = 25;
        static int index = 0;

        static string projectCollectionFolder;
        static Uri projectCollectionUri;

        static WorkItemStore wiStore;
        static WorkItem wItem;
        static WorkItemChangedEvent workItemChangedEvent;
        static string teamProjectPath = "";

        static VersionControlServer versionControlServer;
        static TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection;

        static Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, TeamFoundationIdentity> m_identities = new Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, TeamFoundationIdentity>(IdentityDescriptorComparer.Instance);            

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
        }

        public WorkItemChangedEventHandler()
        {
            TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEvent Started", index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: ProcessEvent entered", index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);


            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            GetTfsServerName();

           projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(serverPath));

            try
            {
                if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
                {
                    workItemChangedEvent = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                    TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: WorkItem " + workItemChangedEvent.WorkItemTitle + " was modified", index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: serverPath -  " + serverPath, index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    projectCollectionFolder = requestContext.ServiceHost.VirtualDirectory.ToString();
                    projectCollectionUri = new Uri(serverPath + projectCollectionFolder);
                    projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri);
                    wiStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                    versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

                    TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: Before process workitem", index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    ProcessWorkItem();
                    TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: After process workitem", index++, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log("WorkItemChangedEventHandler: FUCKING EXCEPTION! =>\n" + ex.Message, index++, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }

        private static void GetTfsServerName()
        {
            try
            {
                string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

                XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDoc.Load(assemblyFolder + @"\Settings.xml");

                // Declare the xpath for finding objects inside the XML file
                XmlNodeList XmlDocNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/tfssettings");
                XmlNodeList XmlDocExt = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/Externaltfssettings");

                // Define a new List, to store the objects we pull out of the XML
                serverPath = XmlDocNodes[0].InnerText;

                ExternalURL = XmlDocExt[0].InnerText;



                XmlNodeList XmlDocNodes2 = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings");

                foreach (XmlNode mailNode in XmlDocNodes2)
                {

                    foreach (XmlNode varElement in mailNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        switch (varElement.Attributes["key"].Value)
                        {
                            case "MailAddressFrom":
                                MailAddressFrom = varElement.Attributes["value"].Value;
                                break;
                            case "SMTPHost":
                                SMTPHost = varElement.Attributes["value"].Value;
                                break;
                            case "Password":
                                Password = varElement.Attributes["value"].Value;
                                break;
                            case "Port":
                                Port = Convert.ToInt32(varElement.Attributes["value"].Value);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", ex.Message);
            }



        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get { return SubscriberPriority.High; }
        }

        private static void ProcessWorkItem()
        {
            var teamProjects = versionControlServer.GetAllTeamProjects(false);

            for (int i = 0; i < teamProjects.Length; i++)
            {
                string teamProjectName = teamProjects[i].Name;
                var teamProject = teamProjects[i];
                Project teamProjectWI = wiStore.Projects[i];

                teamProjectPath = projectCollectionUri + teamProject.Name;



                if (workItemChangedEvent.PortfolioProject == teamProjectName)
                {
                    //get the workitem by ID ( CoreFields.IntegerFields[0] == ID ?!) 
                    //check if any of String changed fields
                    foreach(StringField sf in workItemChangedEvent.ChangedFields.StringFields)
                    {
                        //is the State field
                        if (sf.Name.Equals("State"))
                        {
                            //then notify Reuqester
                            wItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(workItemChangedEvent.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue);

                            string CollGuid = projectCollection.InstanceId.ToString();
                            string Requester = wItem.Fields["Requester"].Value.ToString();
                            string WorkItemId = wItem.Id.ToString();
                            string mail = GetEmailAddress(Requester);


                            SendMail(CollGuid, WorkItemId, mail);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static string GetEmailAddress(string userDisplayName)
        {
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(displayName={0})(objectCategory=person)((objectClass=user)))", userDisplayName);

            SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            ResultPropertyValueCollection values = results[0].Properties["mail"];
            if (values.Count == 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return values[0].ToString();
        }


        private static void SendMail(string collID,string workItemId,string tomailAddrees)
        {

            MailMessage objeto_mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = Port;
            client.Host = SMTPHost;
            client.Timeout = 200000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailAddressFrom, Password);
            objeto_mail.From = new MailAddress(MailAddressFrom);
            objeto_mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(tomailAddrees));
            //objeto_mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("nagarajb@hotmail.com"));
            objeto_mail.Subject = "Work Item Changed:"+workItemId;
            string mailbody = serverPath+"/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=" + collID + "&id=" + workItemId;


            string mailbody2 = "";
            if (ExternalURL.Length > 0)
            {
                 mailbody2 = ExternalURL + "/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=" + collID + "&id=" + workItemId;
            }

            string tables = "<table border=1><tr><td>Work Item ID</td><td>" + wItem.Id.ToString() + "</td></tr><tr><td>Title</td><td>" + wItem.Title + "</td></tr><tr><td>State</td><td>" + wItem.State + "</td></tr><tr><td>Assigned To</td><td>" + wItem.Fields["Assigned to"].Value.ToString() + "</td></tr><tr><td>Internal URL</td><td>" + mailbody + "</td></tr><tr><td>External URL</td><td>" + mailbody2 + "</td></tr></table>";


            objeto_mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            objeto_mail.Body = "<i>Hi " + wItem.Fields["Requester"].Value.ToString() + ","+"</i></br></br></br>" + tables + " </br></br>   Best regards; </br></br>Configuration Management Team</br></br></br>";

            client.Send(objeto_mail);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", "Email Sent");

        }

    }
}
```

No errors or exceptions are thrown in the Event Log either. Tracing TFS (trace=true property in web.config) also was of no help.

Maybe someone could help or shed light on this mysterious case?

UPDATE:

Thanks for a reply Giulio Vian!
Here how it goes:
1) I haven't seen the dependencies broken, plus the constructor `WorkItemChangedEventHandler` is successfully called. That is seen in the Windows Event Log - `WorkItemChangedEvent Started` message is written.
2) I am not sure how to register the event handler.... i'll look that up
3) I am not sure how this works. I thought just copy-pasting dlls in the appropriate folder will do the trick, and there is no need for an account for  the plugin. Mind giving a bit more info on this?
4) yes. Web.config in the main Web config in `Application Tier\Web Services`
5) Yes. Using an account with Administer rights. if i set a break point in the constructor, it is reached. Any other place in the code is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can be wrong.

1. If any dependency is broken, you should see an error in the Event log
2. If you do not register the "WorkItemChangedEventHandler" event source, no message is written
3. Can the user account running the plugin access TFS?
4. How did you enabled the tracing (you pasted a bunch of code, but no configuration)?
5. Have you attached the debugger to the TFS process and set a breakpoint (**do not this on a production TFS**)?

We have collected similar suggestions in the documentation for our plugin at 
https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki.

Comment: @GiuiloVian Thanks for reply! updated the post. couldn't fit it all into the comment.

Comment: Could be that your TFS is 2015.1 or .2 ? There are known breaking changes https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/13/breaking-change-in-tfs-2015-update-1-for-server-side-plugins/ . If you are not in hurry, consider using  https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator or at least, pick ideas and code from it.

Comment: Sadly i am not sure about what TFS version we have, it is surely 2015 but have no clue which update it is. Thanks for the info! i'll take a look and see what i can come up with! I'll keep the thread up to date :)